# how to create a NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am currently reading my coredata like this

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
                    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Manuz" inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext];
                    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
                    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [__managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
                    NSManagedObject *myinfo = [NSManagedObject alloc]
                    for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
                        [self startTheParsingProcess:[info valueForKey:@"manu"]];
                    }
```

I am having some issues with my for statement, its execuing several time and I am not sure why its doing that.. and come to think of it I don't really need it..

I am hoping there is an alternative solution to this where I just initalize the NSManagedObject and then add it to the method call I do in that for statment...

So I guess something like this

```
NSManagedObject *info = [[NSManagedObject alloc] init]; //this is obviously wrong.. 
[self startTheParsingProcess:[info valueForKey:@"manu"]];
```

any help would be awesome!

Comment: u want to create NSManagedObject class (.h,.m files) for your entity 'Manuz'?

Comment: `NSManagedObject *myinfo = [NSManagedObject alloc]`?? This does not make sense to me.. init and semi colon?

Comment: well its not correct but I was just trying to signify creating the object that can be used. pretty much what I am say is how to I change the for statment **NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects** into creating the NSManagedObject... so I can use it  I dont get the key work **in**

Comment: It is looping through each of the results it found...*in* is just a keyword for enumerating each of the items in a collection.

Comment: Ok.. But what actually you want to perform in this code?

Comment: Okay Borrden you have higlighted an error in my code, for some reason each time I run my app it adds a new object into my coredata structure.. I dont know why so I need to find that.. so whats happening in the for statment is that its reading through each one... each time i start the app again there is a another one... so need to find that.

Comment: @anonymous basicly I want to use whats in my entity and run it though a parser method I have made.. however whats happening for some off reason everytime I run the app a new lot of data is added to my entity.. which is making it run several times more than it needs too.. I thought there was an error in the for loop so was looking for a new solution.. however I have now realized there is something else going on in my code that I need to find..

Comment: Inserting an object into core data uses a method which looks like this:  `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` so look through your project for that.  Or you can take a look at the database that is created by your application with a sqlite browser (for the simulator it will be in the Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/... directory) to see what is actually in it.

Comment: okay cool.. I am going though this stuff this morning..

Comment: yup turns out when I was testing it I  was passing values to it outside of my if statement which ment each time it ran it would add a new set of vals.. I forgot about this piece of code... so its fixed now and working sweeeet. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Do not create a NSManagedObject using alloc & init.  If you want to create an instance of an entity "Manuz", you would do so by inserting a new Manuz object into the managed object context.

```
NSManagedObject *newManuz = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Manuz" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```